# Limit with getting info about audience from Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get audienc name aduience id etc we' ve created on our google analytics account. We have around 2,4k audiences list but I can just get 999 of them. I can't find any soultions. Code is below

```
function main() {

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadshe');
   var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sh');

function listRemarketingAudiences(accountId, propertyId) {
  var request = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.list(   
      accountId, 
      propertyId
    );
  var leno = Object.keys(request).length
  console.log(leno);
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("audianceName");
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue("audianceId");
  sheet.getRange(1,3).setValue("audianceDefinition");
  sheet.getRange(1,4).setValue("audianceDescription");
  for ( var i = 2; i <3000; i++) {
    var audianceName = request.items[i+154].name ;
    Logger.log(audianceName);
    console.log(i);
    sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue("elo")
   var audianceId = request.items[i].id ;
    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(audianceId);
//    var audianceId = request.items[i].
   var audienceDefinition = request.items[i].audienceDefinition ;
    sheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(audienceDefinition);
   var audienceDescription = request.items[i].description ;
   sheet.getRange(i,4).setValue(audienceDescription);

  };
}
listRemarketingAudiences('xxxxx', 'UA-xxxxx-1');

}
```

Comment: Have you tried supplying the pagination parameters, as described in the developers guide? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/list#parameters

Comment: can you be more specific? I'm quite new at programming, I'm not sure how code should look like after supplying the pagination parameters,

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are supplying only the required parameters: accountId and webPropertyId. These are necessary to identify the Analytics property, where you are looking for the data.

Based on the documentation, optional parameters can be passed, which are actually in connection with the pagination, which you are trying to achieve.

As the [developer guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/list#parameters) is not mentioning the absolute limit of the result, you could experiment with higher limits, with a code something like this:

```
request = gapi.client.analytics.management.remarketingAudience.list(
    {
      'accountId': accountId,  
      'webPropertyId': propertyId,
      'max-results': 5000
    }
```

If you can't get all the data at once, you need to implement paging yourself, where an other paramerer, `start-index` will be necessary. You need to call the function several times, preferably from a loop, where start index is continuously increased.

```
request = gapi.client.analytics.management.remarketingAudience.list(
        {
          'accountId': accountId,  
          'webPropertyId': propertyId,
          'start-index': 999,
          'max-results': 1000
        }
```

Comment: /thank you, I'm doing it through script editor in google spreadsheet , I did that: – 
<code>function listRemarketingAudiences(accountId, propertyId, maxresults ) {
  var request = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.list(   
      accountId, 
      propertyId,
      maxresults
    
    );
</code>
and I had 
Extra args block must be a javascript object literal
error

Comment: I had Extra args block must be a javascript object literal error

Comment: any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote sth like this:

```
  var optional = {'startIndex': 12,
                   'maxresults': 212};

function listRemarketingAudiences (accountId, propertyId, optional){
var request = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.list(
    accountId,
    propertyId,
  optional.maxresults

);
```

and an error occure:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 9, file "Code")
```